# Windows Local file system

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, windows-8, file-sharing

I am running a desktop on windows and would like to access the files in a certain folders from my laptops via my local Lan network. What is the easyist way to do that?...

My desktop is Running windows 8, laptop 1 is running windows 7, and laptop 2 is running Linux Ubuntu (latest version)

Comment: What version of windows on each computer?

Comment: My desktop is Running windows 8    laptop1 is running windows 7 and laptop2 is running Linux Ubuntu (newist version)

Answer (score 0):

Use file sharing - it's built into Windows.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/file-sharing-essentials

It's very simple to setup for simple sharing of specific folders from your PC to another.

Comment: Yes, that should work but I am running windows 7 on one laptop and the newest version of Ubuntu on the other. Is there any other way, because  you can't use Home group on Linux        -Thanks

Comment: Simple sharing doesn't have to use home group; you can just share folders independently which you can browse in Linux with smbclient and/or mount as folders.